# Can we reschedule the Magento certification exam which is already rescheduled once?

Tags: magento2, certification

> Can we reschedule the Magento certification exam which is already
>   rescheduled once ?

Due to Medical emergency I rescheduled my friend's Magento certification exam with **$95 charge**.

But the now the case is as doctors said he won't be recover till the new rescheduled date, Can I reschedule it again in **No charge** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, you can reschedule test multiple time without any charge before 72 hours of test session.**

As per magento certification **"No Shows and Cancellations"** terms and conditions

> No Shows and Cancellations: I understand I can reschedule or cancel my scheduled test session with less than seventy-two (72) hours' notice and rescheduling for an additional fee.

You can send mail to **support@magento.com** for any additional information.